# How to make a submit button work on a questionnaire

Tags: javascript, html, form-submit, onsubmit

I am making a health questionnaire, I am having a few problems with it. The main problem is the else section. Can someone tell me why it isn't working and help me sort it?

The code I have is:
    
    
     Assignment 4

## Health Questionnaire

---

```
<body>
<form name="form1">
Please enter the following details: <p>
First Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtFirstName"> size="20" maxlength="20"> <p>
Surname: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtSurName"> size="30" maxlength="20"> <p>
Age: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtAge" size="3" maxlength="3"> <p>
Address Line 1: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtAddressline1" size="30" maxlength="30"> <p>
Address Line 2: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtAddressline2" size="30" maxlength="30"> <p>
City: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtCity" size="20" maxlength="20"> <p>
County: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtCounty" size="20" maxlength="20"> <p>
Post Code: <br>
<input type="text" name="txtPostCode" size="10" maxlength="10"> <p>

<input type="submit" value="Check Details" name=validateForm
    onclick="validateForm_onclick()">

<script type ="text/javascript">
function validateForm_onclick()
{
var myForm = document.form1;
if(myForm.txtAge.value === "" || myForm.txtFirstName.value === ""|| 

myForm.txtSurName.value === ""|| myForm.txtAddressline1.value === ""|| 
myForm.txtAddressline2.value === ""|| myForm.txtCity.value === ""|| 

myForm.txtCounty.value === ""|| myForm.txtPostCode.value === "")
{
alert("Please complete all of the form");
if(myForm.txtFirstName.value ==="")
{
myForm.txtFirstName.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtSurName.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtFirstName.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtAge.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtAddressline1.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtAddressline2.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtCity.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtCounty.focus();
}
else
{
myForm.txtPostCode.focus();
}
}
else
{
alert("Thanks for completing the form " + myForm.txtName.value);
myForm.submit();
}
}
</script
</form>
</body>
```

I need to also keep the sizes on the names but need to hide that from the user.
Can someone give me some advice on how to change this?

Comment: You don't seem to have a submit button. Should the last input element have type=submit rather than type=button? Also that long string of else blocks is invalid.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Check Details" name=validateForm
    onclick="validateForm_onclick()"> It is above the script. Is this is the wrong place?

Comment: That is not a *submit* button, it's just a button. If you want it to submit the form make it type="submit".

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Check Details" name=validateForm
    onclick="validateForm_onclick()"> I have changed it, however it now wipes the page when I fill in each section

Comment: That's because it is now actually submitting the form, but the form has no action attribute so it goes to the same page, and if your server-side code isn't set up for that in effect you're just reloading the page. The code shown in the question doesn't seem to have "sections", just one form.

Comment: What code would you use to make it all work?

Comment: A tutorial on how forms work is beyond what I can cover here, especially when you also need help with your Javascript. I suggest finding some tutorials with Google.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice.

Comment: I'd also take a look at the `required` HTML attribute - most of your validation seems to be checking a value is submitted for all inputs, and the required attribute can do this for you without relying on JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your form does not have a submit button. 
Your code:

```
<input type="button" value="Check Details" name=validateForm
    onclick="validateForm_onclick()">
```

Rectified code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Check Details" name=validateForm
        onclick="validateForm_onclick()">
```

Also, the long list of else is illegal in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, I have made them changes. Regarding the long list of 'illegal' code what do I need to change that to to make it work?

Comment: The syntax for if-else-if is wrong. The syntax error must be showing up on your console.
Instead of `if(condition){}else{}else...`, it should be `if(condition){}else if(condition2){}else if(..)....`

Take a look at [if-else-if syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: Ive made them changes but its still not working, could you please send me your version of the code. That way il be able to see what i have done wrong and I can then make the correct changes

Answer (score 0):

**form name=form1** needs to have quotes: **form name="form1"**

And in case you don't want to use submit but stick to a button, insert this in your javascript:

```
else
{
alert("Thanks for completing the form " + myForm.txtName.value);
myForm.submit();
}
```